# Can Guice's @Singleton annotation be inherited?

Tags: java, guice, code-injection

Let's say that I have this class:

```
@Singleton
public class Parent { ... }
```

and this class:

```
public class Child extends Parent { ... }
```

in my Java app, and my app relies on *Guice* injection to create objects. If I create an instance of `Child` through `Injector.createInstance(Child.class)`, wiill that instance be a Singleton automatically (because the parent was annotated as a Singleton), or do I need to explicitly add the `@Singleton` annotation to `Child`?

Comment: annotations are normally not inherited, but why don't you give it a try and see what happens?

Comment: How is Parent a singleton if you can create subclasses, too?  Once you have both a Parent instance and a Child instance, Parent isn't really a singleton anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope - you'd need to annotate `Child` as well. You can set up a simple test to verify this like:

```java
public class GuiceTest {

  @Singleton
  static class Parent {}

  static class Child extends Parent{}

  static class Module extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
      bind(Parent.class);
      bind(Child.class);
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void testSingleton() {
    Injector i = Guice.createInjector(new Module());
    assertNotSame(i.getInstance(Child.class), i.getInstance(Child.class));
  }

}
```