# Guice @Provides with a dependency instances a singleton twice

Tags: java, annotations, singleton, inversion-of-control, guice

I'm wondering how I can bind a singleton to a parameter in a provider.

ie:

```
@Singleton
public class RunButtonController{
    @Inject
    public RunButtonController(EventBus eventbus){ ... }

    public JComponent getView(){
        return view;
    }
    ...
}

public class UncaughtExceptionController{
    @Inject
    public UncaughtExceptionController(
        EventBus eventBus, ..., 
        @Named(DefaultExceptionViewKey) JComponent defaultView)
    { ... }
    ...
}

public class GUIController{
    //another consumer of RunButtonController, arguably the "main" consumer. 
    @inject
    public GUIController(RunButtonController runButtonController,
                         UncaughtExceptionController uncaughtExceptionController, ...)
    { ... }
    ...
}

public class Bootstrapper{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new OptipModule());

        GUIController controller = injector.getInstance(GUIController.class);
    }

    private static class OptipModule extends AbstractModule{

        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(EventBus.class).toInstance(new EventBus("OPTIPGlobalEventBus"));
            bind(JFrame.class).to(GUIView.class);
        }

        @Provides @Named(DefaultExceptionViewKey)
        public JComponent getFrom(RunButtonController runButtonController){
            return runButtonController.getView();
        }
    }
}
```

Putting a breakpoint on my `RunButtonController` constructor, I can see it consistently getting instanced twice. I want it to only be instanced once, and I want 
`defaultExceptionViewProvider == runButtonController` 
to be `true`.

I've used Castle Windsor fairly extensively, but that's the only IOC container I've used, so I'm  new to guice. I'm seeing remnants of visitor behavior all over the place, and guice's documentation makes it pretty clear that the defined behavior of a class (ie, instance once, use this instance, use this factory, ...) doesn't persist beyond the module it was configured for. I'd like to say that I saw it written that when you use an `@Provides`, guice creates a child module for you, so presumably what I need to do is tell this child @Provides-generated module that 'hey, this class is a singleton and I'm in the process of resolving it, so here it is! don't use your own!'

I think that I'm going about this framework the wrong way. I've been smashing down annotations and hitting debug, but perhaps what I really need to do is spend a few hours reading a good tutorial, unfortunately I cannot find one. The JavaDoc has examples, and the webpage publishes them, but they give you very little context and so, having read the article on @Assisted *three times*, I still don't understand it (perhalps that's what I should be using?) Bonus points for somebody who points in the direction of a particularly detailed blogger and a guice entry on his page.

Along those lines, and digressing enormously, I'm wondering what the ramifications are of me trying to pushing this 'hey your default notification area is this other guys view' into my IOC container. Is that maybe domain logic? I don't really want the `UnhandledExceptionController` to know that its view was provided by a `RunButtonController`, and similarly I don't want the `RunButtonController` to know its view is being used for anything other than being stamped out onto the view tree.

thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As posted, it looks like your code should work.** That said, there are a few caveats that could cause singletons to coexist. Double-check the stack trace for each of the constructor calls.

- It may be obvious, but you can create any number of instances outside of Guice's control, and Guice has no way of knowing those instances exist. Double check that nothing in your code calls the `RunButtonController` constructor manually.
- Singleton behavior is enforced within any given injector. If you have two or more injectors in your application, they could each create their own instance of `RunButtonController`. A singleton declared in a parent injector would be visible to any child injectors, though.
- Singletons work *by key*. If you were to remove the `@Singleton` annotation and add this:

  ```
  bind(RunButtonController.class)
      .annotatedWith(Names.named("Foo"))
      .asEagerSingleton()
  ```

  Then injecting `RunButtonController` would get you a new instance every time, but injecting `@Named("Foo") RunButtonController` would get you a separate singleton instance that would return the same every time. That probably doesn't apply to you, because the `@Singleton` is on the class itself, but it has bitten others before.
- You don't seem to rely on inheritance, but remember that [singleton annotations don't inherit from superclass to subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015831/can-guices-singleton-annotation-be-inherited).

Side note: `@Provides` methods don't work via child injectors, but *private modules* do (alluded to as "parent injectors" [in the documentation](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html)). Internally, it's true that a [separate internal module](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/source/browse/core/src/com/google/inject/internal/ProviderMethodsModule.java) is responsible for calling those provider methods, but that doesn't really matter—singletons are shared between modules.

Regarding your digression about sharing views: You're doing fairly well already by injecting `@Named(DefaultExceptionViewKey) JComponent` instead of `RunButtonController`, but if you wanted to be even more implementation-agnostic, you could create an `ExceptionHandlerComponent` interface and code against that.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Under the debugger when it hits by break point in RunButtonController, the top of the call stack on both hits is the same single call to `injector.getInstance(GUIController.class)`. I just hacked the project to pieces so it doesnt compile, I'll check over your list of suggestions. If none of them fix it I can fix it using an old-school singleton and a static `getInstance()`, method, but I'd really rather use regular injection. I'm under NDA so I'm hesitant to go handing out gists, but I'll add some more details. Any chance I found a bug in your nice framework?

Comment: @Groostav If your IDE shows object IDs, can you confirm that you're dealing with the exact same injector instance? (And I'm not a Guice dev, but without a full SSCCE it'd be hard to identify a bug anyway.)

Comment: I just updated the original post with more details, I haven't verified the object ID, but Unless Java's calling main twice...

Comment: Built out your paste into a SSCCE, and could not reproduce the behavior you're describing. Paste this into a new file and try it: http://pastebin.com/NiHEg29x

Comment: In this most recent commit my bugs, gone. I'd like to think that all I've done is manage dependencies not relevant to the one here, but clearly that's not the case. I'll try to run this one down tomorrow. cheers.